# ASP.NET mvc 2 app crashed on Windows 2008 R2 64 server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, windows-server-2008, deploying

I have built a asp.net mvc 2 app, using the .NET framework 4.
It runs OK on my windows 7 (64 bit) machine, but when deploying to the server it gives me the following error:

```
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
```

I suspect it has something to do with mixing 64 bit and 32 bit, but I have no clue whatsoever.  This happens on different windows 2008 r2 servers, so it's not server (hardware) specific.

I did a BIN deployment of mvc 2 (copying system.web.dll, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll, and system.web.routing to the BIN folder)

**Update**

The error occurs as soon as I try to access the database, a MS SQL 2008 server, via Linq-to-SQL.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why it crashed.

Most of the time a CLR.DLL error is caused by an infinite loop or something like that, just something really stupid.

In my case an unreachable SQL server (or rather: incorrect configured connection string) was causing the error. In my code, when reading or writing to the database failed the application tried write a log error to the same database. Which, of course, failed as well and caused an endless loop.

Yes, too stupid.